# Get An Row From Dynamically Allocated 2D Array Pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm pretty much a novice with C++ and have been trouble working my way through pointers.

```
//Define Colormaps (for brevity they are null)
//256 rgb combinations in each colorMap
uint8_t colorMap0[256][3];
uint8_t colorMap1[256][3];
//Insert Color Maps in to a storage array via pointer
uint8_t *colorMaps[] = {*colorMap0, *colorMap1};

//Well define a current Map Index to read from colorMaps
uint8_t colorMapIndex = 0;
//We will define a pointer to the active array that we'll update in loop()
uint8_t *currentColorMap;
```

Occasionally We'll reassign the current color map

```
currentColorMap = colorMaps[colorMapIndex];
```

and other times well get values from it

```
uint32_t c = GetColorFromMap(125);
```

We'll need these functions as well

```
// Create a 24 bit color value from B,G,R
uint32_t Color(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
{
  uint32_t c;
  c = r;
  c <<= 8;
  c |= g;
  c <<= 8;
  c |= b;
  return c;
}

uint32_t GetColorFromMap(byte indexValue)
{
  uint8_t rgb = currentColorMap[indexValue];
  return Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
}
```

The trouble lies in how to get values from the current color map

the current code is giving me 3`'invalid types 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}[int]' for array subscript'` errors in `return Color(rgb[0],...`.

I've tried pointers from the currentColorMap but get:

```
invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}')
```

I have to use a soultion with a low memory foot print as this is going on an arduino. I was previously making a 256x3 byte array that was killing my dynamic memory.... however that compiled. If its not one thing its the other!

Comment: You need to start by learning that c and c++ are different languages, c++ just likes to feel like c, but it can't, c is better. So please choose a language. And I suggest c, because if you pick c++, then they will tell you to use `std::` stuff.

Comment: C code can be compiled as C++; they are fundamentally related languages: they are named similarly for a reason. Also, for CodeMode, I think you are rather knowledgeable about the subject, but hopefully you won't choose a language based off of some random unjustified complaint. Hopefully if you will learn one, you will research them both.

Comment: @iharob Technically the arduino IDE is C++ however I'd prefer a native C solution as I am afraid of the so called std:: stuff

Comment: @CodeMode you don't need to be afraid, if you use c++ carefuly it's a good language, the `std::` stuff are ok, you need to use the appropriate language for the task, I just don't like c++'s syntax, but it doesn't mean it's a useless language, and in fact, the largest project I have ever worked with is c++ because I had to use Qt for a GUI.

Comment: This Doesn't Work Either `return Color(currentColorMap[indexValue][0], currentColorMap[indexValue][1], currentColorMap[indexValue][2]);`

Comment: `uint8_t *currentColorMap;` should actually be `uint8_t** currentColorMap;`. Don't hassle with c-style arrays and raw pointers. Use the appropriate types from the [c++ standard container library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++, a multi-dimensional array isn't actually a set of two arrays like in some other languages. Rather, `int arr[a][b]` is the same as `int arr[a*b]` except that it will do some math behind the scenes. If you think about it, it makes since mathematically. Specifically it allows you to write `int arr[x][y]` which will do the following operation:

```
int arr[x*b+y]
```

Think about it this way: you have each `x` row after one another, which is each populated with `y`s. So if you go by the length of an `x` row you can access that specific entry. So in your example, `rgb` is equal to the `indexValue`th color *byte*, which is not a full color.

However, there is a problem. You have a pointer `currentColorMap` which is the array you currently want to use. But when copying a multi-dimensional array into a pointer, the compiler "forgets" what it used to be. So you, have to do the simple work for it.

```
uint8_t *rgb = currentColorMap + indexValue * 3;
```

What are we doing here? We're simply taking the *pointer* of `currentColorMap` and adding *three times* the index. Why three times? Because your second dimension is three, or, because there are three bytes per color. Then your color is actually a pointer to the real color. You can now treat it as you did before:

```
return Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

Comment: Dude you rock! I bow down before your greatness :)

I found that the `return Color(rgb[index][0]....)` didn't work but the second solution did!